# mb_convert_encoding Unicode Circled Numbers error

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding, converters

I have an issue about the convert encoding in PHP

My Code:

```
$data_row = mb_convert_encoding($data_input['example'],'UTF-8',"SJIS")
```

example

> ①②文字 ----> after run this code ---> ??文字.

Which ‎Character encoding should I use?

Comment: its better if you just stick with utf-8 everywhere and not have to convert

Comment: I think it is not good solution

Comment: @LongAnTruong, why is using UTF-8 everywhere not a good solution? Unicode was designed for exactly this purpose, and UTF-8 is a widely-supported encoding.

Comment: I'm sorry about the question is not clear , this case is when import the csv file which has SJIS format .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result was here .

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195266/iconv-cant-convert-circled-numbers-to-from-japanese-encodings

after update my code from

```
  $data_row = mb_convert_encoding($data_input['example'],'UTF-8',"SJIS")
```

to

```
$data_row = mb_convert_encoding($data_input['example'],'UTF-8',"SHIFT_JIS-2004")
```

It works perfectly.